# Can I bulk import tasks in tfs with having the parent as column?

Tags: excel, tfs, import-from-excel

I've got a list of Tasks in Excel. Now I want to import them in TFS but they all have a requirement as parent. So when I use the Tree I could import them one after another by using cut and paste under the requirement in Excel.

I would like to have the possibility to name the parent in a flat list and having a column for the parent name. Is there any possibility to do this?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flat lists don't support the setting of parents via a column in the excel sheet. You'll need to use the tree view.  Feel free to raise an issue on the Visual Studio user voice site for this if you wish at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com however this is unlikely to change because the tree is a viable option for most people